# Is it possible to connect instances to internet using a GCP VPN?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to connect my default network to the internet using a VPN and I don't want to use OpenVPN for that. I ask if it is possible to connect using a VPN Gateway (GCP), but, I'm found that VPN is used to connect to other VPN networks.

Could Google VPN be used as a real VPN?

Answer (score 0):

> Could Google VPN be used as a real VPN?

Assuming that you mean you would like to connect to Google Cloud VPN using client software running on your desktop, the answer is No.

Google Cloud VPN is used for site-to-site VPNs, and not for client-to-site.

You will need to use a third party product such as OpenVPN to provide client-to-site VPN connectivity.

FYI: OpenVPN is a very good product.

Comment: I need to connect the internal network (in GCP) to the Internet across that VPN, is it possible? (no a desktop client)

Comment: VPNs connect to devices (another VPN endpoint). The answer depends on what you are connecting to. I think that you are trying to provide Internet connectivity to a VPC, so the answer is no. You will need to use an Internet Gateway or a NAT Gateway.